# Matching a string with special characters

Tags: lua

```
str = [[<?php
code
code
?>]]

print(string.match(str, "<?"))    //Actual Output: < , Expected Output: <?
print(string.match(str, "<?php")) //Actual Output: php , Expected Output: <?php
print(string.find(str, "<?"))     //Actual Output: 1 1 , Expected Output: 1 2
print(string.match(str, "<?php")) //Actual Output: 3 5 , Expected Output: 1 5
```

Please explain the reason behind this mysterious output and also suggest a solution to generate the desired output.

Comment: use `string.match(str, (("<?"):gsub("%p","%%%0")))` instead of `string.match(str, "<?")` to have special characters in `match` and `find` patterns properly escaped

Answer (score 1):

Lua match use a pattern, not only an exact string.

more explanations in the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html).

See patterns and magic characters.